# "Error updating" when installing ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, pci

I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my desktop. But repeatedly I am facing the following problem after booting from USB flash drive.

```
[ 0.145979] pci 0000:03:02.0: BAR 1: error updating (0xdf210000 != 0xdf010000)
```

What does this error mean and How can I solve it?

Comment: based on this https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/kernel-fails-to-assign-memory-to-pcie-device-4175487043/ it could be a driver problem. Can you give more information about your setup and desktop ?

Comment: My computer is DELL Optilex 7020 and the processor is Intel core i7. I can't get the command interface as in the link described. Can you explain more to me?

Comment: The link is not a solution, it's just a guide what could be the problem.. Which graphic card do you have ? When you boot do you get the options to choose *Ubuntu *  *Ubuntu(safe graphics) etc..
Did you disabled secure boot ? Which program did you use to install Ubuntu on USB ?

Comment: Yes I get the grub menu it in UEFI boot.

Comment: Yes secure boot is disabled. I have used rufus to install Ubuntu on USB